# Разделение трафика с 2х USB модемов

Tags: mikrotik, модемы, маршрутизатор, шлюз

Подскажите возможно ли реализовать такую схему работы в Mikrotik
Мне нужно  создать две подсети 100 и 133 и каждой привязать свой модем, то есть чтобы клиенты подсети 100 работали с интернетом с модема МТС а клиенты с подсети 133 только с модема теле2.
Что я делаю :

Имеется два usb  модема, через хаб я их подключаю к роутеру.
собственно настраиваю соединение, линки поднимаются.

Далее создаю VirtualAp  для wi-fi второй сети

Все это дело развожу по двум Bridge, создаю dhcp  сервера для каждого из них

Проблема возникает при создании шлюза "Routes"
Как правильно создать шлюзы так - чтобы одна сеть работала только с теле2 а вторая с мтс.Я пробовал делать через Routing mark, но не осилил.
Подскажите в какую сторону копать, заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал такое для списка адресов единой подсети, но думаю что задача от этого меняется минимально.

1. создаете правило маркировки пакетов. Достаточно промаркировать пакеты по отправителю - IP->Firewall->Mangle в новом правиле указать chain=prerouting action="mark routing" newRoutingMark="mark1" и выбрать тип источника: Src.Address если указывать по IP, InInterface если по входящему интерфейсу, Src. Address List если по ранее заданному списку адресов.
   `/ip firewall mangle add chain=prerouting in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=mark1 disabled=no
   /ip firewall mangle add chain=prerouting in-interface=bridge2 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=mark2 disabled=no`
2. Создать маршрут по умолчанию для трафика с указанием марки. Если создаете маршрут самостоятельно то при создании маршрута надо указать в Routing Mark название марки созданной в 1 шаге. Если маршруты создаются динамически, то можно указать только distance и их надо будет пересоздать вручную. Если не отключать динамические маршруты, то в них попадет все что не было промаркировано. 
   `/ip route add gateway=pppoe1 distance=1 routing-mark=mark1 disabled=no
   /ip route add gateway=pppoe2 distance=1 routing-mark=mark2 disabled=no
   /ip route add gateway=pppoe1 distance=10 disabled=no
   /ip route add gateway=pppoe2 distance=15 disabled=no`

И не забудьте про то что надо делать nat для каждого внешнего интерфейса.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, я был рядом с истиной. Вроде все работает , но если я удаляю динамически созданный шлюз(ip=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=pppo1) появляются какие то проблемы с DNS. Кроме яндекса ничего не открывается.

Comment: недостаточно данных. если вы удалили все маршруты по умолчанию кроме маркированных, то сам маршрутизатор не будет иметь выхода в интернет,  равно как и днс сервер на самом маршрутизаторе. Надо у хостов в сети указать адрес внешнего днс сервера или оставить маршрут по умолчанию для самого роутера

Comment: Понял , большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: вместо mangle - ip route rules